# How do I customize my color range for my tmap plot in R?

Tags: r, legend, color-scheme, tmap

I want to plot a map showing crime frequency. I run the command:

```
tm_shape(trinidad) + tm_polygons("Crime_Total", palette = "Reds", colorNA = NULL, title = "Crime 
Frequency")
```

and obtain this result

[image]

I have a few issues with this plot, though. As you can see, the majority of the areas are light red since only a few areas have extremely high frequencies. I would therefore like to have the map show a threshold value of 2500.
Also, how can I get areas with frequency = 0 to show completely white and not light red?

I would envision my legend looking something like this, with the same color scheme applied to the map:

Crime Frequency
white: 0
very light red: 0-500
light red: 500-1000
pinkish red: 1000-1500
red: 1500-2000
dark red: 2000-2500
very dark red: > 2500

I tried looking for a way to specify cutoffs in the tm_polygons function but I wasn't able to find a solution. Is there any way to manipulate the map to get my desired result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code to modify the legend

```
tm_shape(trinidad) + tm_polygons("Crime_Total", style = "fixed", breaks=c(0,500,1000,1500,2000,2500,12000),
                                  palette = "Reds", colorNA = NULL, title = "Crime Frequency")
```

To have the last class as >2500, you can use the highest value in your dataset.